# Python can't set attribute on abstractproperty

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have the following snippet:

```
from abc import abstractproperty

class Base(object):
  @abstractproperty
  def foo(self):
    print 'wat'

class C(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 'test'
    self.bar = 'test2'

c = C()
```

When I execute it, it gives the stacktrace:

```
in __init__ AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

on the line `self.foo = 'test'`.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You need to implement a setter to set a property. And by the way, it it's abstract, the concrete subclass needs to provide a concrete implementation

Comment: @idjaw the attribute is a property, not a method

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini it is providing a concrete implementation to the **property**

Comment: No, it's not. Your class `C` needs a `@property def foo(self): ...` -- that's a valid concrete implementation for the property. Add `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` (which you forgot) to your abstract base class and you'll see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that you forgot to use `ABCMeta` as your metaclass. Change your code to:

**[For Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta):**

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    ...
```

**[For Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/abc.html#abc.ABC)**, any of the following:

```
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta

class Base(ABC):
    ...

class Base(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    ...
```

And you'll see this nice error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
    c = C()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods foo
```

It's telling you that you need a concrete implementation for your abstract property.

But that's not enough: to properly have `self.foo = 'test'` working, you need to implement a concrete setter for your property.

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def foo(self):
        print 'wat'

class C(Base):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        # do something

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        # do something else

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'test'
        self.bar = 'test2'

c = C()
```

Remember that you can use `super()` in your concrete property code to use the code from the abstract property.

**Note:** that [since Python 3.3, `@abstractproperty` has been deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty). Instead, you should use a combination of `@property` and `@abstractmethod`:

```py
class Base(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        ...
```

Comment: I thought a concrete impl of a property would just be setting it, but this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code defines a read-only `abstractproperty`. See [docs on ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty). In addition, you did not set `ABCMeta` as meta class, which is obligatory. Furthermore, an `abstractproperty` is **abstract** which means that it **has to** be overwritten in the child class.

If you want to create a read-write `abstractproperty`, go with something like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta # This is required.

    def getfoo(self):
        pass # Getter for preprocessing when property 'foo' is requested
    def setfoo(self, thefoo):
        pass # Setter for preprocessing when property 'foo' is set
    foo = abstractproperty(getfoo, setfoo)

class C(Base):
    foo = '' # Overwrite abstract property

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'test'
        self.bar = 'test2'
```

Using the code above, you can instantiate your class `C` and set its property `foo`:

```
c = C()
print(c.foo)
>>> test
```